# Including php files into a site page

Tags: php, html, header, include

I am trying to include my **header.php** & **footer.php** file that I have created into every page. And so far its been working!

As soon as I created a new directory e.g /new-site-area - when I then created a new php page and tried to include the header.php this then didn't seam to work?

This is the php include that I am using, and it is working...

```
<?php include ("includes/header.php");?>
```

It just seems to stop working as soon as I try to include it into a page that is in a /directory.

**Example:**

www.mysite.com - header include works
www.mysite.com/new-directory/new-area - header include doesn't work

I can't understand why it would work on my websites root, however not as soon as the page is in a different /area of my site.

*If this is an unfixable problem could somebody please advise a better way of including php files into a site page!*

Thanks!

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: It probably does not work because the directory reference is not the same. You should never hard code the dir reference.

Answer (score 2):

You have to browse into your directory with the return argument "../"

for example, your page

```
www.mysite.com/new-directory/
```

should use

```
<?php include ("../includes/header.php");?>
```

for a 2 level folder like

```
www.mysite.com/new-directory/new-directory2
```

It should be

```
<?php include ("../../includes/header.php");?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `include "../includes/header.php"` - the best would be to write some function that would include it right, for example:

```
function load($file) {
    return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/$file";
}
```

then just use `include(load("header.php"));`

Or if you want your `load()` function to support multiple paths, try something like this:

```
function load($file) {
    $paths = array(
        "includes",
        "some_other_dir/includes"
    );
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$path/$file")) {
            return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$path/$file";
        }
    }
    trigger_error("File $file not found in any of paths", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Then if the file is in any of paths specified, it will be included via `include(load("file.php"));`, if the file does not exist it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework if you don't want to implement a way of resolving the path of your includes. There is a lot of small frameworks that handle this and many other problems.